# Proportion of self-avoiding walks on a square lattice

Tags: code-golf, integer

## The challenge

Given a positive integer `N`, compute the proportion of `N`-step walks on a plane that don't intersect themselves.

Each step can have any of the `4` possible directions North, East, South, West.

A walk intersects itself if it visits a previously visited point.

## Examples

- `N=1`: a single-step walk obviously doesn't intersect itself. So the result is `1`.
- `N=2`: given the first step in any direction, there are `3` possible directions that avoid intersection, and one that goes back to the origin, causing intersection. So the result is `3/4 = 0.75`.
- `N=3`: if the second step doesn't cause intersection, which happens `3/4` of the times, the third step will not cause intersection with probability again `3/4`. So the result is `(3/4)^2 = 0.5625`.
- `N=4`: things become more interesting because proper loops can be formed. A similar computation as above gives `(3/4)^3 - 8/4^4 = 0.390625`, where the second term accounts for the `8` proper loops out of the `4^4` possible paths (these are not excluded by the first term).

## Additional rules

- Output can be floating-point, fraction, or numerator and denominator.
- If floating point, the result should be accurate up to at least the fourth decimal.
- Input and output are [flexible](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) as usual. [Programs or functions](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398) are allowed, in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Test cases

```
1  -> 1
2  -> 0.75
3  -> 0.5625
4  -> 0.390625
5  -> 0.27734375
6  -> 0.1904296875
7  -> 0.132568359375
8  -> 0.09027099609375
9  -> 0.0620574951171875
10 -> 0.042057037353515625
11 -> 0.02867984771728515625
12 -> 0.0193674564361572265625
```

Comment: Related: [OEIS A001411](https://oeis.org/A001411)

Comment: @Downvoter How can I improve this challenge, or future challenges? Any advice you’d like to share?

Comment: I guess the downvoter tripped over their own path when reading this challenge.

Comment: why not allow the output to be the number of paths (like in OEIS)?

Comment: @qwr That was the other option I considered. I settled down on proportion rather than number because proportion has a clearer meaning. ("There are 5916 non-intersecting paths of length 8. Is that a lot? Well, it's a fraction 0.09 of all exiting paths"). Anyway it's too late to change now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```
‘ı×Ƭ¤ṗÄQƑ€Æm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9qZWxsef//4oCYxLHDl8aswqThuZfDhFHGkeKCrMOGbf874oCcIC0@IOKAnTvDhwrDh@KCrFn//zg)

A monadic link taking `N` as its argument and returning a float representing the proportion of non-self-intersecting walks of length `N`. Generates all walks of that length and then checks for intersections, using complex numbers to represent the 2D coordinates.

Thanks to @LuisMendo for saving a byte, and @Mr.XCoder for saving 2 more!

### Explanation

```
‘            | Increment by 1
    ¤        | Following as a nilad
 ı           | - 1i
  ×Ƭ         | - Multiply (by 1i) until no new values, returning all intermediate values
     ṗ       | Cartesian power (with N+1)
      Ä      | Cumulative sums of innermost lists
       QƑ€   | Check whether each list is invariant when uniquified
          Æm | Arithmetic mean
```

Comment: Good idea :-) I also used complex numbers in my code to generate the test cases

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks. Nice challenge!

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw4wjGw9PP7bm0JKHO6cfbgk8NvFR05rDbbn/LYIOtwOZ7v8B) with `‘ı×Ƭ¤ṗÄQƑ€Æm`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thanks! You also brought my R answer under 100 bytes.

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>153 149 144 140 126 118</s> 92 bytes

Here we represent the 2d coordinates as a single integer: We start at `0`, and the directions `N,E,S,W` correspond to adding `+n,+1,-n,-1` where `n` is the input (we could also use any larger number). Using this we generate all possible paths, and then just check for duplicate numbers in those paths.

Thanks @H.PWiz for -26 bytes!

```hs
g n|a<-scanl(+)0<$>mapM(\_->[1,-1,n,-n])[1..n]=sum[1|x<-a,[b|b<-x,c<-x,b==c]==x]/sum[1|x<-a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY0xDgIhEAC/QmEBEU7pLHbvB/cCJBcgehK5DRFNKPg7SmUz1WTm4crzllLvG6PmQJXgKPGjOMNh3l1e@HVVs9FSaUlSkRVGTxNZLJ/d6FZBOWl886CqDAMeMVjEak9/w/bdRWLIRnBl@RXpzfk9xcylQIBN/Gaje7GifwE)

#### Explanation

```hs
--generate all possible paths
    a<-scanl(+)0<$>mapM(\_->[1,-1,n,-n])[1..n]
--count the non-self intersecting paths, compute the ratio to the total
g n|a<- ... =sum[1|x<-a,[b|b<-x,c<-x,b==c]==x]/sum[1|x<-a]
```

Comment: Very clever way to reduce to 1D!

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY0xDgIhEAC/QmEBEU7pLHbvB/cCJBcgehK5DRFNKPg7SmUz1WTm4crzllLvG6PmQJXgKPGjOMNh3l1e@HVVs9FSaUlSkRVGTxNZLJ/d6FZBOWl886CqDAMeMVjEak9/w/bdRWLIRnBl@RXpzfk9xcylQIBN/Gaje7GifwE). I think it can be shorter

Comment: thanks, I feel stupid that I didn't notice the `mapM` opportunity, and the uniqueness check is neat, maybe something to add for the tips!

Comment: @H.PWiz Sorry, I mistakenly attributed your suggestion to another **wiz**ard!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 89 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,S=[0]:n>=len(S)and sum(f(n,S+[S[-1]+d])for d in[-n,-1,1,n])/4.or len(set(S))>n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xDoMwEATr8IorbXFO4oQqkvkEpeXCkbGCBAsCp8jrnaPd3ZndfuWz4lFrdnNc3ikSeHD@Hl7o3TxCDToi0fFdVFZStX7wxoY2BZ3XnRJN8AZsLFtG0LfuKunJHWMRVveo5w6yI//kjq2om8u2TyhyRSLVTf0D)

A recursive approach inspired by [flawr's lovely Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197382/69880). Outputs a float.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 16 bytes

Done with a lot of help from [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo) in [MATL CHATL](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl-chatl).

```
QJ4:!^Z^!YsSdAYm
```

[Try it at MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=QJ4%3A%21%5EZ%5E%21YsSdAYm&inputs=4&version=22.1.0)

Alternative:

```
Q8BPZFZ^!YsSdAYm
```

[Try it at MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=Q8BPZFZ%5E%21YsSdAYm&inputs=4&version=22.1.0)

### Explanation

```
QJ4:!^Z^!YsSdAYm    – Full program. Receives an integer N as input.
  4:                – Range 1...4.
 J  !^              – Raise J (imaginary unit) to those powers*. Yields j, -1, -j, 1.
Q     Z^            – Cartesian power N+1.
        !Ys         – Transpose and take the cumulative sums.
           Sd       – Sort and get the deltas (consecutive differences).
             A      – All. For each column, if it contains 0, then 0, else 1.
              Ym    – Arithmetic mean.
```

<sup><sub>(*): `!` is needed there because [Octave is weird](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53024041#53024041).</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + gtools, <s>111</s>  88 bytes

```r
mean(!apply(diffinv(t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(1,-1,n<-scan(),-n)),n)))),2,anyDuplicated))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs9CoAwDEDhs7glkAoKbo5eJPRHAjWEtoqevnZ43/ZK71dkhYnN8gdBUhJ9oEF8jTXMZ5EAJRpkqQ08LOQW0t1VPyYkp4g0Gq7E@h23ZfHcYkDsW/8B)

[Test suite](https://tio.run/##VY7NCsIwEITvfYo1UNjARqgnKfXmY3gJ@ZFAXUOTSoP47DHFk4cZhjl8M0v1MCnwK5scnoybhHeXjOa/Vm714TTjQcc4F7TB@8AvzOi2qNke70uwuLiIc0gZDQ6kBuJJ7SCUpFhKamp@Is3lusY5GJ2dlbJ@upYwxSVw9ih6O0KfBEHZHwzjmSD9Vgv5BkguwgXEjYWsXw)

Reads `N` from STDIN and implicitly prints the answer as a float.

Thanks to @LuisMendo for a fab challenge and saving 6 bytes! Thanks to @Mr.XCoder for saving 3 bytes (indirectly via my Jelly answer). Thanks to @Giuseppe for saving 10 bytes with an excellent suggestion partially inspired by @flawr’s Haskell answer!

Comment: `any(duplicated(...))` -> `anyDuplicated(...)`?

Comment: Or doing the 1-d reduction inspired by flawr, you can get to [91 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDAXQs7gl8DsoTuLoEbxAqFUKNS02Cp6@@uZ3tXYGUeqklPTSFvc96kNGh@Wc6jSVcJ23icWslUbo7Kr/P8NTD9dD4ZSBlZkxQPRd7pKiFwsbcxvbBw)

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks. The 1-d reduction fails for N=1; I can’t see an obvious way around that that costs fewer than 5 bytes.

Comment: perhaps a nice base R `expand.grid` will work: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dcs9CoAwDEDhs7glkAoKbo5eJPRHAjWEtoqevnZ43/ZK71dkhYnN8gdBUhJ9oEF8jTXMZ5EAJRpkqQ08LOQW0t1VPyYkp4g0Gq7E@h23ZfHcYkDsW/8B)

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks, I’d not used `diffinv` or `anyDuplicated` before; both very handy!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

Uses [flawr's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197382/59487) of reducing to 1D.

```
1‚D(«Iãε.¥DÙQ}ÅA
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9vc2FiaWX//zHigJpEKMKrScOjzrUuwqVEw5lRfcOFQf//NQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 69 bytes

```hs
(%[])
-1%_=1
n%l=sum[(n-1)%map(+d)(0:l)|d<-[1,-1,pi,-pi],all(/=0)l]/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBDsIgEADAe1/RgyS7EdqSeDAG/IEvQNKQVpR0IRvRm28Xnfs8Qt1uRC3aawPhPHZKi9nqrgiy9Z0dFKVR5MCwXxGmE@FnNcppqbTkJBUnLwMRjHZC8uOh5ZBKb/v/uMw9P1N5AURKDBKtMRHN7uz0MBw9tu8SKdxrUwvzDw)

Uses a similar idea to [flawr's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197382/20260) of storing 2D coordinates as 1D values: \$(x,y)\$ is represented as \$x+\pi y\$. Maybe this is unfair because finite precision means that eventually two different coordinates will be represented as the same value. This will take an extremely large input though because `toRational pi` equals `884279719003555 % 281474976710656`.

Instead of updating the position after each move, we `map` the position change onto the list of previously visited coordinates. That way, we can detect a collision by seeing a 0 among the previous coordinates. Because we only check a coordinate the loop after it's added, one extra loop is done, for `n+1` total.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,p=0,*S:n<1or sum(f(n-1,q,p,*S)for q in{p-1,p+1,p-1j,p+1j}-{*S})/4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nwNZARyvYKs/GML9Iobg0VyNNI0/XUKdQpwAorJkGFCxUyMyrLgCKFWgDsa5hFoiRVatbrRVcq6lv8h@kJg@oRqEoMS89VcNQx1LTiouzoCgzr0QjT0cBaJ6m5n8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁰η⊞υ⟦⁰⟧ＦυＦΦ⁺⟦¹θ±¹±θ⟧§ι±¹¬№ικ¿⁼Ｌιθ≦⊕η⊞υ⁺ι⟦κ⟧Ｉ∕ηＸ⁴θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NSwMxEIbv/oo5TiBCC715KlVhQUvvyx7i7nQTmiZNMqn@@zi7qHiar2dentGaPEbjW@vCrfKxXj8oY1JPD/tS3Bxwo8HKdKrFYtXQbwaZzjEDVgVrfXWe5efka8F@qyFpONJsmHCr/tqkBg177sJEX@j@EWphIuMh1sDL5SIrcGfAl1SNL/hGYWaLTrgkl3dz@zHrwpjpSoFpWh2BfCH4FV11JK6/DGrxz07iD6YwPru7mwitMPFTxHdrsECt7drj3X8D) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `N`.

```
≔⁰η
```

Initialise the number of paths to `0`.

```
⊞υ⟦⁰⟧
```

Start off with a path with no steps.

```
Ｆυ
```

Perform a breadth-first search of the paths.

```
ＦΦ⁺⟦¹θ±¹±θ⟧§ι±¹¬№ικ
```

Take @flawr's list `1, N, -1, -N` and add the last position on the current path to each value. Filter out results that already appear in that path, and loop over the remaining self-avoiding values.

```
¿⁼Ｌιθ
```

If this path already has `N` steps...

```
≦⊕η
```

... then increment the count of found paths.

```
⊞υ⁺ι⟦κ⟧
```

... otherwise construct a new path and add it to the search list.

```
Ｉ∕ηＸ⁴θ
```

Print the proportion of self-avoiding paths.